# printing an variable of an object that's inside an array that's inside an object

Tags: php, arrays, object, for-loop, echo

Well, ive been trying to get my crm to print multiple contacts for each company but i cant get it to work

Company is a class,companycontactis a class

//class called company

```
 function __construct($idklanten,$naam,$adres,$postcode,$stad,$contacten){
    $this->idklanten=$idklanten;
    $this->naam=$naam;
    $this->adres=$adres;
    $this->postcode=$postcode;
    $this->stad=$stad;
    $this->contacten=$contacten;

}
```

//class called contact

```
    function __construct($idcontactklanten,$voornaam,$tussenvoegsel,$achternaam,$tel,$email,$klantID){
    $this->idcontactklanten=$idcontactklanten;
    $this->voornaam=$voornaam;
    $this->tussenvoegsel=$tussenvoegsel;
    $this->achternaam=$achternaam;
    $this->tel=$tel;
    $this->email=$email;
    $this->klantID=$klantID;
}
```

//getname for a contact

```
  function getNaam() {
    if(strlen($this->gettussenvoegsel()) == 0) {

        return $this->getvoornaam()." ".$this->getachternaam()."";
    }
    else {


        return $this->getvoornaam() . " "  . $this->gettussenvoegsel() . " " .  $this->getachternaam();
    }
}
```

//function for getting the names from my object company,array with objects of contacts

```
 function getcontacten(){           
        $ct=$this->contacten[$teller];
        $txt="";
        for($teller=0;$teller<10;$teller++){
            $txt+=$ct->getNaam()."<br>";
        }
     return $txt;
}
```

then on my index page when i call getcontacten() it does not work comparing to my other get function which do work. it just outputs a 0

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your biggest error would be the following:

```
$txt+=$ct->getNaam()."<br>";
```

Should be

```
$txt.=$ct->getNaam()."<br>";
```

Because to append to a string you use ".=", not "+=".

Also I don't know if the other part of you code works, I would write something like the following:

```
$txt = "";
foreach ($this->contacten as $ct){
    $txt .= $ct->getNaam() . "<br />";
}
return $txt;
```

or

```
$txt = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->contacten); $i++){
    $txt .= $this->contacten[$i]->getNaam() . "<br />";
}
return $txt;
```

Comment: There is a little mistake in your last loop : `$` instead of `$i`

Comment: Still doesnt work when render the page it displays a 0 not even a empty string which i find weird.

Comment: Do some debugging then. Start with letting the method just return a string value, like  "return "Some text";" and se if you can print that. Then try inserting my code but still at the end of the method returning a regular string to see if the problem is in the code itself or somewhere else. Also make sure to check that $this->contacten have any values and that it is indeed an array.

Comment: somewhat fixed it only now outputs             " Alexander van Meel
Saco Koelma

Fatal error: Call to a member function getxNaam() on a non-object in /home/nextlead/domains/nextlead.nl/public_html/klanten/spreker/klanten.php on line 63"

Comment: is says "getxNaam" but you function name is "getNaam", maybe a spelling-error somewhere. What's your current code for the function getcontacten ?

Comment: nvm fixed it works like a charm now. thanks for trying to help